# Passing a UITapGestureRecognizer touch onto an underlying UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a UITableViewCell which contains a UITextView. I'd like for certain characters within the UITextView to be tappable - which I'm using TextKit to achieve. I've setup a UITapGestureRecognizer on my UITextView, but am using it to determine which glyphs within my text container have been selected.

The issue I'm running into is that I'd like to pass the tap onto the underlying UITableViewCell if non-relevant glyphs are tapped. What's the best way to achieve this?

```
NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = textView.layoutManager;
CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:textView];
location.x -= textView.textContainerInset.left;
location.y -= textView.textContainerInset.top;

NSUInteger characterIndex;
characterIndex = [layoutManager characterIndexForPoint:location
                                       inTextContainer:textView.textContainer
              fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints:NULL];

if (characterIndex < textView.textStorage.length)
{
    NSRange range;
    id value = [textView.attributedText attribute:@"applicableCharacters" atIndex:characterIndex effectiveRange:&range];
    if(value)
    {
         // Handle this tap, don't pass to the UITableViewCell
    }
    else
    {
        // Don't handle this tap, let the UITableView call tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
    }
}
```

Comment: How about giving your subclassed cell a public property containing its indexPath. Then have a delegate protocol on the cell informing its delegate (the tableView's delegate) something like `textViewCancelledTapInCell:self` when the datasource receives the delegate call it can simply perform `[self didSelectRowAtIndexPath:receivedCell.indexPath`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my own comment, but skipping the delegate part as it is not necessary.

Public property on the cell-subclass:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *indexPath;
```

Set this from the datasource when returning cell for indexPath...

Inside your else:

```
UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *) self.superview;
[tableView.delegate didSelectRowAtIndexPath:self.indexPath];
```